# Refactor two for's into java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm facing a small problem to rewrite my two for's into java 8 streams.

```
// This is a method parameter
Map<String, Collection<String>> preSelectedValues;

List<PersonModel> parameters = parameterSearchService.getParameterNames();

for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>> it = preSelectedValues.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
     Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry = it.next();
     for(int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
          if (entry.getKey().startsWith(parameters.get(i).getName())) {
               it.remove();
          }
     }
}
```

I've tried following streams to have the same behaviour as before:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> filteredParameters = preSelectedValues.keySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> isParameterValid(x, parameters))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> preSelectedValues.get(v)));
```

`isParameterValid` method:

```
private boolean isParameterValid(String parameterId, List<PersonModel> preSelectedValues) {
     return preSelectedValues.stream()
            .anyMatch(v -> !v.getName().startsWith(parameterId));
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is filter the "preSelectedValues" map which starts with "parameterId". But somehow when I'm using streams either it filters everything or nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isParameterValid` method doesn't have the same logic as the original loops, since:

1. You switched the instance and argument in the call to `startsWith`.
2. Calling `anyMatch` with a `!v.getName().startsWith(parameterId)` only tells you whether at least one element of the `List<PersonModel>` doesn't start with `parameterId`. Your original condition for keeping the entry in the `Map` was that **all** the elements of `List<PersonModel>` don't start with `parameterId` (or actually, the other way around - `parameterId` doesn't start with any of the names of elements of `List<PersonModel>`).

Therefore I negated the method to return the condition for removing an entry from the `Map`:

```
private boolean isParameterInvalid(String parameterId, List<PersonModel> preSelectedValues) {
     return preSelectedValues.stream()
            .anyMatch(v -> parameterId.startsWith(v.getName()));
}
```

And then the stream pipeline can look like this:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> filteredParameters = preSelectedValues.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> !isParameterInvalid(x.getKey(), parameters))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

BTW, since your original loops mutate the original `Map`, you can achieve the same with `removeIf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to modify the original map you can use `removeIf`:

```
preSelectedValues.keySet().removeIf(
    key -> parameters.stream()
            .map(PersonModel::getName)
            .anyMatch(key::startsWith)
);
```